# Retrieving dropdown values from partial view during post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to get the selected dropdown value from partial view and included in the CategoryID in the Book class...

```
[Authorize]
    public PartialViewResult GetAllCategory()
    {
        ProcessSVC.Category newCategory = new ProcessSVC.Category();
        newCategory.ChildCategories = obj1.GetAllCategories(String.Empty);
        return PartialView(newCategory);
    }
```

GetAllCategory.cshtml (PartialView)

```
@model MvcAdminTemplate.ProcessSVC.Category
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ParentID, new SelectList(Model.ChildCategories, "ID", "DisplayName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Create View:

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        MvcAdminTemplate.ProcessSVC.Book oBook = new ProcessSVC.Book();
        return View(oBook);
    }
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model MvcAdminTemplate.ProcessSVC.Book
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }
@Html.Partial("_LeftMenu")
<!-- content -->

<h2>Create</h2>
<div class="col-md-10">

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Books", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
     <div class="row"> 
         <div class="bootstrap-admin-no-table-panel-content bootstrap-admin-panel-content collapse in">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Add Book</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BookName, new { @class = "control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BookName, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
                            <p class="help-block"> </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = " control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control ", type = "text" })
                            <p class="help-block"> </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group divCategory">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            @Html.Label("Parent Category", new { @class = " control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BookId, new { @class = "hdn-id" })

                            @Html.Action("GetAllCategory","Books")

                            <span class="help-block"> </span>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

After submission of the above form i need to get Book attributes and Category "Selected Category".

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ProcessSVC.Book oBook)
    { 
        oBook.LanguageID = 1;
        _service.AddBooks(oBook.ActualPrice,oBook.ActualPriceString, oBook.Author, oBook.BookId, oBook.BookName, oBook.CategoryID, oBook.Currency, oBook.CurrentPrice, oBook.CurrentPriceString,
                             oBook.Description, oBook.DiscountPercentage, oBook.DiscountValue, oBook.LanguageID,
                             oBook.NativeLanguageName, oBook.Publisher);

        TempData.Add("SuccessMessage", " New book " + oBook.BookName + " Added !");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this line in your GetAllCategory.cshtml file

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", new SelectList(Model.ChildCategories, "ID", "DisplayName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 2):

To correctly bind your model, you need to create the dropdown in the main view. This line in you partial view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ParentID, ....
```

will render a select

```
<select name="ParentID" ...
```

but you model is expecting a property named `CategoryID`

In you `Create()` method, generate the `SelectList` and assign to a view model property or to `ViewBag` and then (instead or `@Html.Action("GetAllCategory","Books")` use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryID, ....
```